# Bootstrap col-sm-4 text vertical align

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem to vertically-align my text in a col-sm-4 div. As you can see text is not vertical-align. How to resolve it?

[image: img]

here is my html code

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1 class="section-title"> HOW NIBOOK WORKS</h1>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><img src="img/Profile.png" class="how-it-works-step-icon">
      <h1 class="how-it-works-title">Become a "NI"booker</h1>
      <h2 class="how-it-works-subtitle">Create your profile and start sharing your skills and services to locals</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><img src="img/bookmark.png" class="how-it-works-step-icon">
      <h1 class="how-it-works-title">Get booked from locals</h1>
      <h2 class="how-it-works-subtitle">Meet in your convenient place to provide your talent</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><img src="img/page.png" class="how-it-works-step-icon">
      <h1 class="how-it-works-title">Receive your money</h1>
      <h2 class="how-it-works-subtitle">Get your money directly to your account</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my css

```css
.how-it-works-title {
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 18px;
 margin: 25px 0 15px;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 10px;
}
.how-it-works-subtitle {
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 18px;
 line-height: 18px;
 margin: 25px 0 15px;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 10px;
 font-weight: lighter;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.how-it-works-step-icon {
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
}
.section-title {
 font-size: 28px;
 font-color: #4C535D;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 18px;
 margin: 0;
 padding-top: 50px;
 padding-bottom: 60px;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.section-subtitle {
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: normal;
 letter-spacing: 1.5px;
 margin: 10px 0 0 0;
 text-align: center;
}
```

I am new on bootstrap, css etc therefore I am sorry if this is a very beginner question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is the final result with all images are vertically align just one issue with you is images size I copied all you code and resize images to a same size of 88px * 87px and all work fine. i provided a line through the images for reference that all are vertically align

[image]

Answer (score 2):

try giving same size to your images i.e `profile.img , bookmarkg.png , page.png` it looks like your images are of different size  , also as an alternative you can use `font-awesome` fonts instead of using these images